# Dnx for Wpf (Or Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, dnx

Will (or does) the DNX project support frameworks other than ASP.net (Such as WPF or windows forms)?  I'd love to create some Wpf class libraries using the newer json project style (and native NuGet package support), but everything seems to be geared towards Asp.net.

Comment: From their website: DNX was built for running cross-platform ASP.NET Web applications, but it can run other types of .NET applications, too, such as cross-platform console apps. Source: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/overview.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dnx is only for ASP.NET 5 projects (web, console or library).
It doesn't support WPF.

Comment: Someone figured out how to do it with a Windows Service: https://taskmatics.com/blog/host-asp-net-in-a-windows-service/

Comment: I am now looking into alternatives like the deprecated OWIN (I am just working on a POC) and http://nancyfx.org/.

Answer (score 2):

The project.json/xproj based project model (I would not call it DNX projects) can indeed be used to build nuget class libraries for scenarios beyond ASP.Net and DNX.

If you specify in your project.json a SDK like net451 you can additionally add frameworkassemblies like "PresentationCore" or "PresentationFramework" and then start coding in class files against WPF. So you can create a class library with it (i just tested it). It builds and packages itself to NuGet. That NuGet you can use then in your normal WPF project.

It is important to understand the concept of a SDK when talking about the new .Net Framework things: DNX is a SDK similar to UWP or the .Net Framework (WPF/WinForm). The SDK then specifies which CLR and BCL are used in combination with the features of the SDK. Consequently, this project format does not target the DNX SDK (from the architecture) but any SDK. In the end a class library is IL which has references to DLLs. Support for direct references with normal .csproj is planned (IMHO).

But there are restrictions: The project format is new, not yet well supported and integrated, there is no and maybe never will be a WPF designer etc.